# Alignment of truth values with connectives in truth table

Tags: tables, math-mode, alignment, logic

I want to typeset a truth table where the truth values of a complex formula are aligned with the corresponding connectives as shown in the attachment. Would someone know a solution? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What should the alignment be? Centred, I assume.

Comment: This could be done in a basic tabular. What have you tried?

Comment: @Werner The aim is to align the truth values (0s and 1s) with the logical connectives in the wffs (the not or the implication in not-A implies B). In my answer below, for example, you can see I've not done the final column because the truth values aren't quite centred under the main logical connective (ampersand). The question assumes discipline-specific knowledge. Without it, it is unclear as well as lacking an MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've provided no code, so I don't think I ought to answer this question. However, this only required a quick modification to code I happened to have.

Basically, you can use a `tabular` with `c` and `@{}` column and column separation specifiers. It's a bit fiddly, but it works reasonably well. The final column in this example and simple negations of atoms are left as exercises for the reader.

When separating two wffs or two sentential letters, use `cc`. When separating part of a wff from another part, use `c@{}c` to avoid the separation between columns.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\newcommand*{\tnot}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}|c@{}cc@{}c@{}c@{}cc}$P$&$Q$&$R$&$\tnot$&$(P \lor R)$&$\tnot$ & $(Q $ &$\,\&\,$&$\tnot R)$&$\tnot P \,\&\, \tnot Q$\\
  \hline
  1&1&1&0&1 &1&&0&&0 \\
  1&1&0&0&1 &0&&1&&0 \\
  1&0&1&0&1 &1&&0&&0 \\
  1&0&0&0&1 &1&&0&&0 \\
  0&1&1&0&1 &1&&0&&0 \\
  0&1&0&1&0 &0&&1&&0 \\
  0&0&1&0&1 &1&&0&&1 \\
  0&0&0&1&0 &1&&0&&1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignment with connectives in truth table]

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for me breach! I tweaked you solution for my use a bit:
```
  \begin{longtable}{||c|c|c|c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c||}
  \hline
  $A$&$B$&$A \land B$&$\lnot$ &$($&$\lnot$ & $A $ &$\,\lor\,$&$\lnot$ & $B)$
  \\
  \hline
  \hline
  1&1&1 &\textbf{1}&&0&&0&0& \\
  1&0&0 &\textbf{0}&&0&&1&1& \\
  0&1&0 &\textbf{0}&&1&&1&0& \\
  0&0&0 &\textbf{0}&&1&&1&1& \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Cheers!

Comment: @pahohu The trick is to keep track of your columns. If you make a mistake, add several extra columns temporarily because it is easier to figure out where the error is. (But maybe you are less prone to typos than me.)